# Take photo from app and send it to email (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-camera, android-file

I need in my android application take photo which set to ImageView and after button click open email application with this photo as attachment.

```
File photoFile;
```

button to take a photo event:

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}
```

activity result:

```
if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
    imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

    //photoFile how to set path of imageBitmap ?
 }
```

and send email button which not work ... (java.lang.NullPointerException: file)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"fake@fake.edu"});
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"On The Job");

intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));

intent.setType("image/png");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Share you on the jobing"));
```

Comment: you can send your own uri to store image or you can retrieve the uri of the taken image and just use that uri